# Should I check for root when using Branch.io?

Tags: android, branch.io

Should I check for root access before initiating Branch.io?

```
// Branch.io
if (!CommonUtils.isRooted(this)) {
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
}
```

I'm worried about referral fraud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: is there any particular reason you're concerned about this? We usually recommend not awarding referral points until after your users are authenticated within your app, and the Branch SDK also uses the Android ID to protect against referral fraud. I don't see any reason why you *couldn't* do a root access check, but it's probably unnecessary in most situations.

Comment: Alex, so is this the correct way of doing it: I create a custom event (e.g. phone_verified), then I create a Rewards Rule (e.g. Referring user gets 1 credit the first time users they've referred triggers phone_verified)?

Comment: @Andrew bingo! That is exactly right. Just be sure you're only triggering `phone_verified` *after* the new users are confirmed to be unique